# Openshot doesn't launch with "failed to import" message

Tags: openshot

Openshot stopped working on my friend's laptop. Running it in a terminal produces this. I suspect a python library it needs was removed.

```
------------------------- ERROR 1 ------------------------------
Failed to import 'from openshot import main'
Error Message: cannot import name main
----------------------------------------------------------------


------------------------- ERROR 2 ------------------------------
Failed to import 'from openshot.openshot import main'
Error Message: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_cursor'
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Tried:

- Reinstalling openshot
- Searching for the error reveals [this bug](https://lists.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/msg06654.html), but I don't have the locale problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try renaming the openshot config folder and restarting openshot i.e.

```
mv ~/.openshot ~/.openshot_backup
openshot
```

N.B. looking at the OpenShot forums - this solution is frequently quoted for these short of python issue.

<sub>[source](https://answers.launchpad.net/openshot/+question/106532)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, all was working fine but suddenly openshot stop functioning!

I've found a solution:

1. First i reinstalled `ffmpeg`...
2. Then i uninstalled openshot
3. I cleaned up after with Ubuntu tweak...
4. After that i manually delete the folder `.openshot` in my personal files (use Crlt H, to see the hidden files)...
5. Rebooted my pc...
6. Finally i reinstalled openshot...

And it worked just fine ... :D

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem in the `~/.openshot/config.xml` file.
I don't know if it's a rule, but in my case it's always related to the `<vpane_position>` value.

Replacing in a broken file:

```
<vpane_position>700</vpane_position>
```

with the deault value:

```
<vpane_position>375</vpane_position>
```

for me does the trick.

If it works for you, for safety, you could create a backup of a working *config.xml* file to be able to restore it **without loosing your actual configuration**:

```
cp ~/.openshot/config.xml ~/.openshot/config.xml.backup
```